# Calling a Variable from a project to another C#

Tags: c#, reference

i want to pass a value from a variable from a project to another after referencing project B to A, after referencing, i still don't know how to read it

```
    //Project A
namespace projectA{
public partial class hello : Form
{
public string value;
}
}
}
```

and for Project B

```
using projectA{
namespace projectB{
public string value2 = value;
}
}
```

please help :(, i already added project A to B through add reference and when i type projectA.... there is only one method shown which is the partial class

Comment: Can you show the real code? You can't declare a variable in a namespace scope.

Comment: The code you've shown makes no sense.  It's not clear what you mean by "access a variable in another project".  When one project references another, it can see the public *types* in that project.  You can declare instances of those types, invoke methods on those types, etc.  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Review core OO concepts about instantiation and `new` in C#. `value` is an instance member of `hello`. You may create a `hello` and then read `value` from the instance you created. You may also make `value` static on `hello` so that it's common to all `hello`s you create and read it directly as `hello.value`. I recommend against doing that, though, because you're clearly confused about object instantiation and that's the better solution more often than not.

Note- It's weird to have a different project call your main form. It's far more common for your main form to call your different project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to declare a [static class member](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx), you can do it like this:

```
public partial class hello : Form
{
    public static string value;
}
```

And then you access it with `hello.value`, beware that **this is bad design**, by doing things like this you are going to make code that is hard to understand and hard to maintain.

Of course maintainable code is not something you will accomplish if you are learning so that's not a big deal, you should first understand the basic concepts and learn what does it mean for something to be "static", what does it mean to "instantiate" a class, what are interfaces, abstract classes, events, delegates, lambda expressions, inheritance, extension methods, properties and so on

--EDIT--

Just noticed how wrong the code in projectB is (not valid C#), see if you can understand the code below:

```
using projectA;

namespace projectB{
    class YouMustHaveAClass { //C# does not allow you to declare variables that belong to no class
        public string value2 = hello.value;
    }
}
```